# How to create array in matlab based on a specific function

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to create an array in Matlab that will store tk = k * T / N  from k = 0 to k = 64, and T and N are the constants 4 and 64 respectively. The equivalent c code being this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    tk[i+1] = i * T / N;
}
```

I believe matlab indexing begins from 1, for what ever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
k = 0:64;
T = 4;
N = 64;
tk = k * T / N;
```

This will generate a 65 element array `tk`. And yes, Matlab indexes from `1`. It is not the only programming language to do so, but it does take some getting used to if you come from a `base 0` language.